# Lag between 'Created Time' and 'Start Time' in GCS import job to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I have a BigQuery job that is bringing in data from GCS each night. Typically, these jobs take ~5 minutes to run, as the data in GCS is somewhat large and is compressed. However, last night, I had a job that, while submitted at the appropriate time, did not start until almost 4 hours later. Details below:

**Creation Time**   May 10, 2017, 12:34:00 AM

**Start Time**  May 10, 2017, 4:00:28 AM

**End Time**    May 10, 2017, 4:01:56 AM

Is this expected? Is there a way I can reduce this lag? This delay did cause problems with our other ETL processes, so I'd like to avoid it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

There was a [recent outage](https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/bigquery/18028) that caused a backlog for imports, though the issue is resolved now. You can get updates about Google Cloud incidents either through the [status page](https://status.cloud.google.com/) or by [subscribing to the RSS feed](https://status.cloud.google.com/feed.atom).